# WordPress PHP Memory Limit Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having issues with increasing my WordPress Memory limit.

So here is a copy of my Site Health Score under Server.

```
Server architecture Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.87.el6.x86_64 x86_64
Web server  LiteSpeed
PHP version 8.1.16 (Supports 64bit values)
PHP SAPI    litespeed
PHP max input variables 3000
PHP time limit  300
PHP memory limit    512M
PHP memory limit (only for admin screens)   2048M
Max input time  -1
Upload max filesize 2048M
PHP post max size   2048M
cURL version    7.84.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1p
Is SUHOSIN installed?   No
Is the Imagick library available?   Yes
Are pretty permalinks supported?    Yes
.htaccess rules Custom rules have been added to your .htaccess file.
```

As you can see, my PHP Memory Limit is still 512M. But the limit for admin screens is 2048M.

I have it set in php.ini.

Note that the PHP Max limit, max input, max file, max post size, are all set in the php.ini and seem to be

This is my php.ini

```
display_errors = Off
memory_limit = 2048M
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
max_input_vars = 3000
max_execution_time = 300
```

This is in my WP_CONFIG

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2048M' );
```

This is my .htaccess

```
# PHP MEMORY LIMIT
php_value memory_limit 2048M
# END PHP MEMORY LIMIT
```

Comment: Is `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` defined in your wp-config.php file?

Comment: @JoshBonnick Thank you I forgot to add that as well as the .htaccess content. In the question.